# How can I pass a parameter to another, before data is fetched in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I got a stored procedure `dbo.getTree` with one parameter "@order". Since it is T-SQL the "@" at the beginning of the parameter is necessary.

When I add that stored procedure to Crystal Reports it will generat a parameter @order.

Now the problem is that the program calling the report, requires me to name the parameter, for fetching the data, "order" without the "@".

So now i got two parameters "order" and "@order".

How can i pass the value of "order" to "@order" so the right stored procedure is called.

Comment: What do you mean by before data is fetched

Comment: Well at some point Crystal executes the sql Query to get the data.  To get the right data, the Parameter @order needs to be set before that point. Think it's possible with the command 'beforereadingrecords'

Answer (score 0):

First: You can pass your parameter using code behind like this:

```
        ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
                ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new         ParameterDiscreteValue();
                paramField.Name = "mo"; remember this is your parameter name at your crystal report 
                paramDiscreteValue.Value = "02";
                paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
                paramFields.Add(paramField);
```

Second: You have to put your parameter into your query at crystal report     command i suggest, if you want a dynamic data result on it, for example it has a     parameter of startdate and enddate.